# Declare pointer to a function that accepts a struct... from within the struct definition?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

Thanks for your time! I've been looking around a lot and found answers which *almost* address my question, but not quite.

```
typedef struct
{
    int menuparams; //lots of these here
    void (*menufunction)(MENUSTRUCT);   //points to "void functionname(MENUSTRUCT *menu)"
}MENUSTRUCT;
```

I have a situation where I want to use a struct to store a function pointer. My code reads an array of these structs (checking a variable in each) and upon determining the appropriate one to use, follows its function pointer to the necessary function.

However, the function(s) in question accept a pointer to that exact same struct type, because they may need to perform some work on *another* struct of the same type. The pointer for this other struct is passed when the function pointer is followed.

My current implementation seems to work, but I want to know if I'm going to cause myself trouble in the future. It compiles and runs just fine, but I get the following warning on the line declaring the function pointer:

> warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration

This makes sense, because my struct doesn't exist before I've finished declaring it. But I can't figure out how best to rewrite this such that it's happy having the struct contain a reference to its own type. I've looked into forward-declaring the struct but the compiler gets grumpier the further away I move from the above implementation.

If I tried:

```
typedef struct menu
{
    int menuparamss; //lots of these here
    void (*menufunction)(menu);  
}MENUSTRUCT;
```

It does at least compile and work, but with the same warning.

Since it seems to work it's technically not the end of the world, but if at some point in the future the MCU might spontaneously burst into flames because of my stupidity, it would be best I know now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy, just use the complete type name, or forward declare the typedef:

Option 1:

```
typedef struct menu {
    int menuparamss;
    //Must use the whole type name, including the "struct" keyword
    void (*menufunction)(struct menu *);  //SHOULD BE A POINTER to the structure
}MENUSTRUCT;
```

Option 2:

```
typedef struct menu MENUSTRUCT;

//Without typedef
struct menu {
    int menuparamss;
    void (*menufunction)(MENUSTRUCT*);  //SHOULD BE A POINTER to the structure
};
```

Comment: Wow... that *was* easy! I've somehow managed to waste a morning playing with this (I'm really not sure how).

Comment: OP is unclear about what she wants (using `MENUSTRUCT` as the function argument but indicating that `menufunction` should accept a pointer to a `MENUSTRUCT` in the comment), but "MUST BE A POINTER" is not correct. Parameters in function prototypes can have incomplete type (that is, `void (*menufunction)(struct menu);` would be valid inside the structure declaration).

Comment: @masfo It is true, my mistake. The parameter can be the complete struct. Anyway, since it is C (not C++) and thus lacking copy constructors and so, he should be using pointers, other way it has little sense. I left my answer with the pointers, but in the comment instead of using *MUST*, I am using now *SHOULD*

Answer (score 1):

Define type MENUSTRUCT first, and then the struct MENUSTRUCT.

```
typedef struct MENUSTRUCT MENUSTRUCT; 
struct MENUSTRUCT
{
    int menuparams; //lots of these here
    void (*menufunction)(MENUSTRUCT*);
};
```

Comment: Thanks muchly, this seems to be what LoPiTaL was saying too. I think I may be a little lost on the syntax of structs and how typedef applies. More reading to do!